# How to combine ARRAYFORMULA + QUERY?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

"Please advise on how to correctly input the formulas to get the desired result as shown in the picture.
Task:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14tpPliM_3b7RIikSimvdzLjkFq3CexPKbtOEuD4aIKU/edit#gid=171798102

1. Лист1 (used as a database) where information is entered and then distributed to ЯБЛОКИ,ГРУШИ,СЛИВЫ.
2. On Sheets (ЯБЛОКИ,ГРУШИ,СЛИВЫ) I applied the ARRAYFORMULA function to import images from the "PNG" sheet, but the import formula from Лист1 was immediately disrupted.
   Here is the desired version on the "ГЛАВНЫЙ" sheet."
   [image]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

The `query()` function returns images as `null` values. Use `filter()` instead, like this:

```
=let( 
  data; vstack('ЯБЛОКИ'!A2:G; 'ГРУШИ'!A2:G; 'СЛИВЫ'!A2:G); 
  filter(data; len(choosecols(data; 1)) + len(choosecols(data; 3))) 
)
```

See
[let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535),
[vstack()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13191461),
[filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197)
and
[choosecols()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13197914).